# What is the difference between NPSApp and StandardApp on npyscreen?

Tags: python-3.x, npyscreen

I need to create a Python CLI application using npyscreen, but the documentation is not clear how to create a UI app.

My app will have a one controller, one service layer and a main script. In the main script I call the controller and the controller loads the service layer, but, what is the difference between use a NPSApp or StandardApplication for main class?

```py
class Controller(npyscreen.NPSApp):
```

```py
class Controller(npyscreen.StandardApp):
```

Which should I use as best practice and when not to use one of them?

Answer (score 1):

StandartApp is deprecated and may throw errors with the latests versions of Python (for ex : 3.7)
Otherwise, npyscreen [official documentation](https://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/application-objects.html) recommands NPSAppManaged.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution :-). If you have it handy, adding a link to that documentation would be an excellent improvement (though  not a requirement). Highest quality answers tend to receive more upvotes over time. Links to source docs make it very easy for visitors to quickly verify & learn more.